# Appium; py.test; python; Same tests for two apps with different package names

Tags: python, appium, pytest, ui-testing

I'm testing app that has to be build in 2 ways, both daily, paralelly etc. This specific app requires one build with fake API and second with real backend.

At the moment I have all the tests marked like this:

```
@sanity
@real
@fake
def test_TC101_first_time_use(self):
```

And running specific tests for each build (some tests has to start for both versions some can be started only on one of them).

Today developers changed package name of fake API version so both versions can be installed at the same time.

Question: Is it possible to make my code dependent on version that is tested at the moment?

For example if test is started by: *py.test -v -m "real"* run test with:

```
desired_caps['appPackage'] = 'com.companyname.appname'
self.driver.find_element_by_id("com.companyname.appname:id/button").click()
```

but when test is started by: *py.test -v -m "fake"* run test with:

```
desired_caps['appPackage'] = 'com.companyname.appname_fake'
self.driver.find_element_by_id("com.companyname.appname_fake:id/button").click()
```

I've tried looking for info how to do this but didn't found any specific (and fast/easy) way solve this problem. I hope someone can help me with this.

edit:
as a workaround I'm using simple bash script that replaces all names in *.py files before starting testing but I'm still wondering if this is possible to do other way.

Answer (score 0):

In pytest you can specialize the test depending on command line. 
You will need to use the addoption() in conftest.py
for example:
def pytest_addoption(parser):
    parser.addoption("--all", action="store_true",
        help="run all combinations")

for more details explanation see:
http://pytest.org/latest/example/parametrize.html

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
I actually saw that method, but frankly speaking failed trying to use it.

Atm I'm using ${PACKAGE_NAME} and variable injection on Jenkins, works fine but it's not problem-free solution. I'll try again with that parametrization when got more time.

Comment: I have used pytest_addoption() and it works very nice.